# compare consecutive columns cell values and replace the other column values

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe shown below where I am comparing consecutive values in `lse` column. If the value of `lse 0` followed by `1`, I want to put the `END_DATE` of `lse` with `0` value as `NA`
Input:

```
END_DATE      lse   
2016-01-20     0  
2015-08-16     1
```

Expected output:

```
  END_DATE     lse   
        NA     0  
2015-08-16     1
```

I have tried the code below, but it is not working and not throwing any error.

```
for (i in length(loan_test1$lse)){
  if (length(loan_test1$lse) == 0 & length(loan_test1$lse)+1 == 1) {
    loan_test1$END_DATE[i] <- "NA"
  }
}
```

can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(END_DATE = seq.Date(from = (today()-99),to = today(),by=1),lse = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))

df <- df %>% mutate(leadlse = lead(lse))

condition <- df$lse == 0 & df$leadlse ==1

df$END_DATE[condition] = NA

df <- df %>% select(-leadlse)
df
```

or more simply:

```
df <- data.frame(END_DATE = seq.Date(from = (today()-99),to = today(),by=1),lse = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE))

df$END_DATE[(df$lse == 0 & lead(df$lse) == 1)] <- NA
```